# Is it possible to retrieve rulename inside a Lambda function called by an Iot rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I need to disable the rule once it gets triggered and sends data to lambda function. So, my approach will be if the lambda function gets triggered if i can information on which rule triggered it i can disable it.

Comment: Unclear. Unless you can show some code, this question is likely to get closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Well you could edit the IoT rule to send its name as part of the payload it is sending to the Lambda function.... Otherwise I'm not sure how you would get the name.

Comment: I had to follow the same approach,appened rulename to select statement while creating the rule.